# how to print a model to file with JuMP/Julia

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization, operations-research

The function print(model) outputs the model in the console.
How can I print the model in a file (e.g. lp file) ?

Best

Michael.

Comment: I only tried print(model, "model.lp"), which does not seem to work

Comment: I don't have `JuMP` instaled to test, but `print` can take a first positional argument of the type `IO`, the default is `STDOUT`, so I think this should work: `open("model.lp", "w") do f; print(f, model); end`.

Comment: you can also execute the script in the terminal (with the print statement in the script) and capture the output: `julia script.jl > output.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Thank's ! This works:

```
f = open("model.lp", "w")
print(f, model)
close(f)

# Using `do` one doesn't have to remember to call `close(f)`
open("model.lp", "w") do f
    print(f, model)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Julia's JuMP has inbuilt method writeLP, which takes Model and filename to the model is to be written.

`writeLP(m::Model, filename::AbstractString; genericnames=true)`

More details can be found here
[JuMP Documentation](http:////http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/refmodel.html)